# How to implement futures composition

Tags: scala

I have a method:

```
def findUserById(id: String): Future[Option[User]]
```

Now i want make another method, based on it:

```
def findUserById(ids: Seq[String]): Future[Seq[User]]
```

But i have some problem with using futures. How to implement futures composition properly?

I have an implementation(not tested), but i think it can be made easier. Also i'm not sure about performance of that implementation:

```
  override def findUsersById(ids: Seq[String]): Future[Seq[User]] = {
    val futures = ids.map(id => findUserById(id))
    val filtered = Future.sequence(futures).map(_.filterNot(_.isEmpty)).map(_.map(_.get))
    filtered
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace `sequence`+`map` with `traverse`, and `filter`+`map` with `flatten`:

```
def findUsersById(ids: Seq[String]): Future[Seq[User]] = 
  Future.traverse(ids)(findUserById).map(_.flatten)
```

In general `Future.traverse` is more succinct than `Future.sequence`, and is a bit more effective, because it avoids creating an intermediate `Seq[Future[T]]`.

Comment: Seconds late :D

Comment: Can you please also explain about the `performance of this implementation` ? A brief description about `how Future works` in this case would be extremely helpful.

Comment: @oblivion I'm sorry, I don't understand what you want to know about performance and how Future works. As for performance, this is probably one of the most effective approaches you can do with `Future`s (it's also possible to remove the last `map` as well, but I think it's too much code for a small gain).

Comment: @oblivion https://gist.github.com/thwiegan/ea089ac4d12894abce8e6b118028d1c7 This is similar to what happens, when you use Future.traverse. It's just a short form for applying a function which returns `Future`s to a list of values and `fold`ing / `flatMap`ping over these futures and therefore combining them to one future. @Kolmar if this helps the others you can add the code to your answer, if you want.